# Microphone stopped working after switching from NVIDIA to nouveau

Tags: nvidia, sound, microphone, nouveau

I was getting terrible performance from the proprietary NVIDIA drivers, so I switched to nouveau using software-properties-kde. Performance is much better, but my microphone stopped working.

It's a Realtek ALC256 sound card.

Output from `lspci -v | grep Audio`:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
```

Output from `pactl list cards`:

```
Card #0
    Name: alsa_card.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_201604140001-00
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 7
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Generic USB Audio at usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:6.2:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6.2/3-6.2:1.0/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-Generic_USB_Audio_201604140001-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "03f0"
        device.vendor.name = "HP, Inc"
        device.product.id = "056b"
        device.product.name = "USB Audio"
        device.serial = "Generic_USB_Audio_201604140001"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "USB Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: yes)
        input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 55, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Stereo Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6555, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5500, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5565, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo Duplex (IEC958) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5555, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        iec958-stereo-input: Digital Input (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Part of profile(s): input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo
        analog-output: Analog Output (type: Analog, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Part of profile(s): output:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo

Card #1
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 8
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x6053bc8000 irq 189"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a0c8"
        device.product.name = "Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 39268, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 38668, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5965, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5765, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5765, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5765, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5765, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra5: Digital Stereo (HDMI 6) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra5+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 6) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5765, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra5: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 6) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra5+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 6) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra5: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 6) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra5+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 6) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra6: Digital Stereo (HDMI 7) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra6+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 7) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5765, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra6: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 7) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra6+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 7) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra6: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 7) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra6+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 7) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra7: Digital Stereo (HDMI 8) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra7+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 8) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5765, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra7: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 8) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra7+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 8) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra7: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 8) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra7+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 8) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra3+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra3+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra4+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra4+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra4+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra5+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra5+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra5+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra6+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra6+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra6+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra7+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra7+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra7+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "DELL P2415Q"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (type: HDMI, priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (type: HDMI, priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (type: HDMI, priority: 5600, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra3, output:hdmi-stereo-extra3+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra3, output:hdmi-surround-extra3+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (type: HDMI, priority: 5500, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra4, output:hdmi-stereo-extra4+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra4, output:hdmi-surround-extra4+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra4, output:hdmi-surround71-extra4+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-5: HDMI / DisplayPort 6 (type: HDMI, priority: 5400, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra5, output:hdmi-stereo-extra5+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra5, output:hdmi-surround-extra5+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra5, output:hdmi-surround71-extra5+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-6: HDMI / DisplayPort 7 (type: HDMI, priority: 5300, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra6, output:hdmi-stereo-extra6+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra6, output:hdmi-surround-extra6+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra6, output:hdmi-surround71-extra6+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-7: HDMI / DisplayPort 8 (type: HDMI, priority: 5200, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra7, output:hdmi-stereo-extra7+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra7, output:hdmi-surround-extra7+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra7, output:hdmi-surround71-extra7+input:analog-stereo

Card #2
    Name: bluez_card.04_FE_A1_08_EB_42
    Driver: module-bluez5-device.c
    Owner Module: 28
    Properties:
        device.description = "JBL Flip 4"
        device.string = "04:FE:A1:08:EB:42"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "speaker"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_04_FE_A1_08_EB_42"
        bluez.class = "0x240414"
        bluez.alias = "JBL Flip 4"
        device.icon_name = "audio-speakers-bluetooth"
    Profiles:
        headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 30, available: yes)
        a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 40, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: a2dp_sink
    Ports:
        speaker-output: Speaker (type: Speaker, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Part of profile(s): headset_head_unit, a2dp_sink
        speaker-input: Bluetooth Input (type: Bluetooth, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Part of profile(s): headset_head_unit
```

Comment: You can't have Nvidia drivers for a Realtek sound card. If it stopped as a result of switching out the gpu drivers, then it was connected through the gpu sound card. run `lspci -v | grep Audio` and `pactl list cards` and post output please.

Comment: @NateT updated the OP